# Showing that $\frac{m}{n}$ is positive if $mn > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

We are given that $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q} \iff  qm = pn$

We define $\frac{m}{n}$ as positive if $mn > 0$

Show that the definition of $\frac{m}{n}$ is well defined.

Attempt:

What I need to show is that for any fraction equivalent to $\frac{m}{n}$ that the definieiton is also satisfied.  So let's take $\frac{p}{q}$ from the same equivalence class as $\frac{m}{n}$. Since they are from the same equivalence class this means:  $$qm = pn$$

I'm not sure what kind of algebraic manipulation I should try. I know that I would like to arrive at $pq > 0$ and I feel that it just involves getting $qm = pn \implies mn = pq$.

But  how to get this?

Comment: My interpretation is that you must prove that this relationship *is* an equivalence.  Which it isn't. as $0*a = b*0$ so $\frac 00 = \frac ab$ and $0*c=d*0$ so $\frac 00=\frac cd$ but we need not have $ad=bc$ or $\frac ab=\frac cd$.

Comment: Or you sure you are suppose to prove the definition of $\frac mn$ is well-defined (if that is a definition of $\frac mn$ it's a bit vague and circular) or are you  supposed to prove the definition of "positive" is well defined?  If the later it a matter of showing that if $mn> 0$ and $\frac mn = \frac pq$ then $pq > 0$.

Comment: @fleablood it is the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $mn>0$ and $m/n=p/q$. Then $mq=np$ and so $m^2q^2=mnpq$. If $pq<0$, then $mnpq<0$: a contradiction with $m^2q^2>0$.

To add some details, note that $m\ne0$, otherwise $mn=0$, which is impossible. Since $q\ne0$, we have $mq\ne0$ and therefore $(mq)^2>0$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it without contradiction?

Comment: @dc3rd Consider $pq=\frac{(mq)^2}{mn}$

Comment: @egreg Can you do $pq = \frac {(mq)^2}{mn}$ directly.  We know that $(mq)^2 > 0$ and that $mn>0$ bot we don't know that if $a>0;b>0$ then $\frac ab >0$ do we?  I mean, we do if we defined $q$ to be an ordered field, but if we did that then what's the *point* of defining "positive"?  We'd just say $q$ is positive if $q > 0$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, sure: the fact that $(mq)^2=mnpq$ guarantees that $(mq)^2$ is a multiple of $pq$, so the quotient is an integer. We have reduced the problem to one about the integers.

Comment: Yeah, but... we are still doing a proof by contradiction, aren't we?  We know $pq = \frac {(mq)^2}{mn}$ is an integer but how do we know it is a positive integer except by pointing out if it were negative or zero we'd get a contradiction?  Do we have a prop or axiom that if $a = bc$ and $a> 0; b>0$ then $c>0$.  We can easily prove that, but I don't see how without a proof by contradiction.  (On the other hand there is nothing wrong with a proof by contradiction....)

Comment: @fleablood The OP is trying to define an order on the rationals; obviously the properties of the order on the integers must be known. Prove by induction on $b$ that if $a=bc$, $a>0$ and $b>0$, then $c>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{pq}{q^2}$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps. If I take that expression I end up with $mq^2 = pqn$ I could attempt to multiply through, but I still don't see an end result..

Answer (score 0):

$pqn^2 = q^2 mn\ge 0$.

If $pqn^2 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $p=0$ or $q=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $pq = 0$

Comment: Is the last line to conclude that since  $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$ then $p\neq 0$ and $q\neq 0$ ?